# What is the most common allophone of r after θ in British English, like in [θri:]?

Tags: british-english, phonetics, received-pronunciation

I ask because post-alveolar r could not be used after dental θ. My intuition tells me that it should be alveolar r, but I have not found on the Internet any confirmation for it.

Comment: you could try listening to some words on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/thrice/#en)

Comment: A more interesting question is whether it's voiced or not.

Comment: I believe only (some) Scots ever have an alveolar tap there today. For everyone else it's just a squishy approximate. There used to be some other dialects 50+ years ago where you had a bit of that, but I don't know that anyone still speaks them.